# https site not working on php upgrade

Tags: php, joomla, https

I tried to upgrade Joomla version from 3.3.6 to 3.4.1 which ended up in "could not open joomlaupdate.xml for writing" error. I had to upgrade php from version 5.3 to 5.5 which ended up in the https site not working.http site works fine.Now I've downgraded to 5.3 and still the same issue. I have my site configured in Amazon AWS. I see that openssl is enabled in  my php configuration.Need help in solving the issue

Comment: Looks like your https host is running under another user that haven't enough permissions.

Comment: So did the update happen or did it die part way through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the httpd configurations have been overwritten.Had to recopy the configurations and restart the service and everything was fine.